# How to use results from models directly inside a controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created this following model (see below). I have managed to fetch data from my database and send generated result to the view by creating a variable called `$data['get_company']`. However, I can't figure out how I can use these results from the model in my Controller without using a foreach loop.

**Model**

```
class Company_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function fetch_company($id = NULL) {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('customer_company_profiles_id', $id);
        $this->db->from('customer_company_profiles');
        $this->db->order_by('customer_company_profiles_id', 'desc');
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return $query->result();
        }

    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index($id = NULL)
{
    $id = $this->input->get('id'); 
    $data['get_company'] = $this->Company_model->fetch_company($id);
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('company/company_index', $data);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

Is there a function like `$something_something->get_company->get_this_row('ID')` so that I can avoid using foreach loops inside a controller and how do I proceed?

Comment: [Take the time to do the "news" tutorial in the official documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html).  This is pretty comprehensive and clearly explains this exact scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `return $query->result()`, use `return $query->row()` in your model. This will return a single row which you can access normally, instead of having to first reference an array.

E.g. in your view you could then do:

`echo $get_company->title;`

[Relevant section in CI manual.](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows)

Comment: Thank you, just what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do I need to create a second model if i also want to pass this data to my view, since I can't use $data['get_company'] when returning $query->row()?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You can use `$data['get_company']` when returning `$query->row()`.